# Add a dot notation in Label SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to return my label in SQL so they look as dot notation.
Something like this should be return:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
| product.attribute   | product.order    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     product A       |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

However, when I try to insert the dot in my label.
It returns me an error.

I am sure it is something obvious that I missed.

Example of query :

```
SELECT product as "product.attribute", Count(Order) as "product.order",
from orderTable
Limit 100
```

Comment: You are not using PL/SQL if you are using `LIMIT`.  Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: `product as "product.attribute"` is valid SQL - what is the error message you get? However `Count(Order)` is not, because `order` is a reserved keyword. You would need to use `count("Order")` instead

Comment: First of all, you need to `GROUP BY`...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using MySQL, in this case you should use backticks:

```
SELECT `product` AS `product.attribute`, COUNT(`order`) AS `product.order`,
FROM `orderTable` LIMIT 100
```

Otherwise the engine will complain about using reserved keywords (like `order`).

Answer (score 1):

I depends on the database:

- In Oracle, DB2, or PostgreSQL you can do:

  ```
   SELECT product as "product.attribute"...
  ```
- In SQL Server, or Sybase you can do:

  ```
   SELECT product as [product.attribute]...
  ```
- In MariaDB or MySQL you can do:

  ```
   SELECT product as `product.attribute`...
  ```

Comment: Thanks... I need to find out more.
I already tried all of them and none of them work.

Comment: Well... what's the database you are using?

Comment: I am digging into that because it is a service hosted by a Partner.